# DropDown Value is not changing If changing another Dropdown

Tags: jquery

```
$('#drpBPGrp').empty();
$.each(Result.drpBI, function (name,value)
{
    $('#drpBPGrp').append($('<option></option>').val(value.BPGrpId).html(value.BPGrpName));
    $('#drpBPGrp').trigger("chosen:updated");
});
Sort("#drpBPGrp");
```

Comment: Can you try `$('#drpBPGrp').trigger('liszt:updated');` ?

Comment: Please give the formatting some love. It's hard to read now

Comment: You need to provide more code on what you are trying.. what are your dropdown HTML .. what is the plugin you are using ..

Comment: Thanx @BharatPatidar  it is working, But The null value is not updating and it  shows old values.